# How to create a class factory of multiple classes with different classes that take different parameters but same return type?

Tags: c++, factory, std-function, typeinfo, class-factory

I ask this question here to hear from a real human perspective.

I want to make a class factory with the following signature:

```cpp
Component* (GameObject*, ...)
```

For some context, this is my ComponentFactory class:

**.h**

```cpp
#pragma once

// Dependencies | std
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

// Dependencies | CoreEngine
#include "Component.h"
#include "GameObject.h"

class ComponentFactory {
    // Object
    public:
        // Properties
        std::vector<std::pair<const type_info*, std::function<Component* (GameObject* gameObject)>>> factory = std::vector<std::pair<const type_info*, std::function<Component* (GameObject*)>>>();

        // Constructor / Destructor
        ComponentFactory();
        ~ComponentFactory();

        // Functions
        void addRegistry(const type_info* typeInfo, std::function<Component* (GameObject*)> contructor);
        Component* create(GameObject* gameObject, const type_info* typeInfo);
};
```

**.cpp**

```cpp
#include "ComponentFactory.h"

// class ComponentFactory

// Object | public

// Constructor / Destructor
ComponentFactory::ComponentFactory() {

}
ComponentFactory::~ComponentFactory() {

}

// Functions
void ComponentFactory::addRegistry(const type_info* typeInfo, std::function<Component* (GameObject*)> constructor) {
    std::pair<const type_info*, std::function<Component* (GameObject*)>> registry = std::pair<const type_info*, std::function<Component* (GameObject*)>>(typeInfo, constructor);
    factory.push_back(registry);
}
Component* ComponentFactory::create(GameObject* gameObject, const type_info* typeInfo) {
    for (const std::pair<const type_info*, std::function<Component* (GameObject*)>>& registry : factory)
        if (registry.first == typeInfo)
            return registry.second(gameObject);
    return nullptr;
}
```

The problem with my code is that certain components take more than just `GameObject*` as an argument. It needs to be able to return `Component*`, the first parameter must be `GameObject*` and from there on, any other parameter and any amount of them. For example:

```cpp
Component* (GameObject*, ...)
```

The goal is to pass a `const type_info*` to the component factory, the `GameObject` and its arguments, and get the `Component*` pointer as a result.

Note: My component factory must be an object because I need different component factories and I'm trying to build a `has a` relationship with a much larger code.

Note: `Component` is a class that other classes derive from.

Note: Each `Component` object has a `cont type_info* typeInfo` variable. Its children do, too.

In the end, it should look like this:

```
componentFactory.create(gameObject, *typeid(someClass), ...)
```

Here is an example JSON that I am reading from, as requested in the comment section. Once it is read, I try to create the objects specified in it. As you can see, `type_info.name()` is saved as `type` in the file. I match that to the `type_info` stored in the component factory.

```json
{
    "gameObjects": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Camera Game Object",
            "transform": {
                "position": [
                    0.0,
                    0.0,
                    0.0
                ],
                "rotation": [
                    0.0,
                    0.0,
                    0.0
                ],
                "scale": [
                    1.0,
                    1.0,
                    1.0
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "transformRelationships": null,
    "components": [
        {
            "gameObjectIndex": 0,
            "type": "class Camera2D",
            "data": {
                "graphicsContextIndex": 0,
                "viewSize": 16.0,
                "backgroundColor": [
                    0.15000000596046448,
                    0.15000000596046448,
                    0.15000000596046448,
                    1.0
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "gameObjectIndex": 0,
            "type": "class CameraController",
            "data": {
                "stength": 1.0
            }
        },
        {
            "gameObjectIndex": 0,
            "type": "class GameObjectController",
            "data": {
                "strenght": 0.10000000149011612
            }
        },
        {
            "gameObjectIndex": 0,
            "type": "class EmptyComponent",
            "data": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Since the typeid is known at compiletime, why is a factory needed? Why not just create the objects directly?

Comment: Do you want to pass the variable arguments values in the create call, or do you want them to be specified in addRegistry and therefore fix for all created objects of that typeid?

Comment: Because every component has its own ```const type_info*``` stored.  Every child class has its own ```const type_info*``` as well. So, I pass that and once the ```const type_info``` is matched, I call the function associated with the contructure. Also, I need to read a JSON file and create these objects.

Comment: Wouldn't an `enum` be simpler than using `type_info*`? When you call `create`, you've unpacked the constructor arguments from the JSON file I assume? In that situation, haven't you also extracted the actual type of object to create? Perhaps you can show an example JSON file and the expected objects to create from it? Some JSON libraries can be made to deserialize objects nicely.

Comment: @JojakimStahl I do have to pass the variable argument values in the create. How that will affect the ```addRegistry``` function is something I am wondering about right now.

Comment: _"I do have to pass the variable argument values in the create"_ - It seems like you need a parameter pack.

Comment: Why is `create()` type-erased in the first place? Why can't `create()` be templated with a component type? (Then you can pass the optional parameters as a parameter pack.) Also, obligatory reminder that writing an empty destructor like this is harmful (declaring any destructor removes implicitly generated move operations, so any move of your class turns into a copy).

Comment: @TedLyngmo No, an ```enum``` would break the entire game engine I have designed. It has the capability. I considered it and implemented it once. It was so hard to maintain because can be an unlimited type of components.  I will see if I can post a sample JSON in the question. But, the type_info.name is stored in the JSON as well. So, yes, I know exactly what type I have on hand.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat The function ```create``` is type-erased because of the design of my game engine. Game objects has a list of components. Game objects only care to have a derived type of Component. Additionally, I want as many aspects of the code to be free of templates because back in the initial stages of the game engine development it significantly slowed down my compilation time. because of using templates. It was so slow that I have no words to describe how big of a pain it was sometimes to edit a single class.

Comment: I want to thank everyone who took the time to contribute to this question. I appreciate each and single one of your responses. Also, I did not know about the consequences of empty destructors. I will look into it. I am also looking into parameter pack, but will not use that if I find a solution that does not use templates.

Comment: Honestly, you guys gave me a temporary solution. I'll just add a constructor to the ```Component``` class that takes a ```nlohman::json``` / ```nlohmann::ordered_json``` and have each child component use that constructor. The only flaw I can think of this approach is that I will have to implement a similar constructor for each type of file type I want to load components from. I will implement this factory problem no matter what though. I think the factory is the way to go once I figure out how to implement it because it is the most scalable approach.

Comment: *"Game objects only care to have a derived type of Component."* Templating the `create()` function doesn't prevent that. *"want as many aspects of the code to be free of templates"* Welp, can't do anything with that.

Comment: Let's invent a very concrete example. You have a vehicle factory. A vehicle can be a car, a boat, or a plane. A car needs its number of wheels to be specified, a boat needs its sail area, and a plane needs its engine type (propeller or jet). Clients want to order vehicles. What kind of data can be reasonably expected from them?

Comment: // Copy an paste in notepad

nlohmann::json json;
// Read json file
// Create game objects
// Assign transform relationships
// Create components
if (component.getTypeInfo() == &typeid(Car)) {
    car_wheel_definition carWheelDefinition;
    carWheelDefinition = json.at(carWheelDefinition);
    return new Car(gameObject, &typeid(Car), carWheelDefinition);
    // This is the patter that I need to follow because of Box2D
}
else if (component.getTypeInfo() == &typeid(Car)) {
    // Same approach
}
else if (component.getTypeInfo() == &typeid(Car) {
    // Same approach
}

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI The comment was not properly formatted when I posted it. So, I will describe what is going on: Read the entire JSON, create the game objects from JSON, assign transform relationships from JSON, create components from JSON: If type is car, create wheelDefinition struct, call ```new Car(gameObject, &typeid(Car), wheelDefinition)``` using the factory class. Apply same principles for the other types. I will say that the only reason why I am using this approach because Box2D requires FixtureDef and BodyDef in the constructor to create bodies and fixtures.

Comment: I don't see why you need `&typeid(Car)` as an argument to the `Car` constructor. Have you had a look at [`from_json`](https://json.nlohmann.me/api/adl_serializer/from_json/#examples)?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes. I have the following: ```inline void to_json(nlohmann::json& json, const Component& component) {    json = component.to_json();
}``` 
The Component::to_json, to_ordered_json, from_json, from_ordered_json are all virtual, so my child classes can correctly parse to and from json objects. But, how would I know that a json represent a child class from component? Therefore, I store ```type_info.name()``` and use that to be able to tell which component I am dealing with. I'd like know more about you point though. I am not sure if I addressed your point correctly.

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm asking what the client of the factory should supply to the factory. Not what the factory should do inside. If the client passes the JSON down to the factory, that's totally reasonable. But if the client is supposed to parse the JSON, it doesn't make much sense at all.

Comment: You need something that parses any JSON that describes your object, extracts the object type only as a string, and uses a map from strings to object creation functions. It is not recommended to use `type_info.name()` for this purpose though. It is non-portable and subject to change.

Comment: @ChristopherBarriosAgosto Did I misunderstand what you are trying to do? If there's anything in my answer that doesn't seem to make sense, please provide more info so that I can correct it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using two of your `Component`s and assume an implementation similar to this:

```cpp
namespace ns { // your namespace

struct Component {
    virtual ~Component() = default;
};

struct Camera2D : Component {
    Camera2D(std::size_t graphicsContextIndex, double viewSize,
             const std::array<double, 4>& backgroundColor) :
        graphicsContextIndex(graphicsContextIndex),
        viewSize(viewSize),
        backgroundColor(backgroundColor)
    {}

    std::size_t graphicsContextIndex;
    double viewSize;
    std::array<double, 4> backgroundColor;
};

struct CameraController : Component {
    CameraController(double strength) : strength(strength) {}

    double strength;
};
```

Then a factory, `componentFactory` below, could simply be a function with a map from class name to a function that instantiates said class. Since you want `Component*` and the classes presumably inherit from `Component`, this factory function returns a `std::unique_ptr<Component>`.

```cpp
template<class T>
std::unique_ptr<Component> getComponentPtr(const json& j) {
    // use the nlohmann::adl_serializer:
    return j.get<std::unique_ptr<T>>();
}

std::unique_ptr<Component> componentFactory(const json& j) {
    static const std::unordered_map<std::string_view,
                                    std::unique_ptr<Component>(*)(const json&)>
    functions{
        {"class Camera2D", &getComponentPtr<Camera2D> },
        {"class CameraController", &getComponentPtr<CameraController> },
    };
    const auto& type = j.at("type").get<std::string>(); // class name
    const auto& factfunc = functions.at(type); // get the function
    return factfunc(j); // and call it
}

}  // namespace ns
```

For this to work, you also need to add `nlohmann::adl_serializer` specializations for your types:

```cpp
namespace nlohmann {
template <>
struct adl_serializer<std::unique_ptr<ns::Camera2D>> {
    static std::unique_ptr<ns::Camera2D> from_json(const json& j) {
        const auto& data = j.at("data");
        return std::make_unique<ns::Camera2D>(
            data.at("graphicsContextIndex").get<std::size_t>(),
            data.at("viewSize").get<double>(),
            data.at("backgroundColor").get<std::array<double, 4>>()
        );
    }
};

template <>
struct adl_serializer<std::unique_ptr<ns::CameraController>> {
    static std::unique_ptr<ns::CameraController> from_json(const json& j) {
        const auto& data = j.at("data");
        return std::make_unique<ns::CameraController>(
            data.at("strength").get<double>()
        );
    }
};
}  // namespace nlohmann
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/x4P9Wrn9j)